# Struct & Enum, Combobox.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, winforms, struct, combobox, enums

The program is a minidatabase-ish thing for product ordering purposes, where I keep the unique orders in a struct, and the productNames in an enum (for practice basically). I only have 3 productnames (Product0, Product1, Product2), and they are added to a combobox (`cbo_productNameEdit.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(productNames));`).

Anyway, after saving an order, I want this combobox to change it's selected item to the saved product's name, but it fails to do so. I checked it with a MessageBox, to see if it didn't store it properly...

```
MessageBox.Show(Orders[cbo_productID.SelectedIndex].productName.ToString());
cbo_productNameEdit.SelectedItem = Orders[cbo_productID.SelectedIndex].productName;
```

... the messagebox returned Product2, which is indeed the correct one, but the selected item stayed at Product0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do to solve it is to set the *SelectedIndex* instead of *SelectedItem* property on the combobox. By default Enums are 0 based integers, so the index will corespond to the value of the enum.

```
cbo_productNameEdit.SelectedIndex = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(productNames),
                             Orders[cbo_productID.SelectedIndex].productName.ToString());
```

Comment: **1.** Enums are not 0 based integers. You can use enum values with negative integers or values can starts from other numbers then 0. **2.** Asuuming that `SelectedIndex` will be always same as value of selected enum is far away from good solution.

Comment: 1. As default they are, that is what I meant. 2. He wanted a answer to the question given, and this solution works. I agree that it isn't the best way though

Comment: If for example he will have enum with values `{0, 1, 4, 5}`, your solution will not work. And sorry, but from phrase _Enums are 0 based integers_ is difficult to understand that this is only by default :)

Comment: I know it wouldn't work in that case. And thats fair :) I'm new here and have to get used to the details in explaining i guess

Answer (score 0):

Because you used `.DataSource` property for filling `ComboBox` with items
You need to use `.SelectedValue` for setting selecting item

```
cbo_productNameEdit.SelectedValue = Orders[cbo_productID.SelectedIndex].productName;
```

From MSDN: [ComboBox.SelectedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)